# Regex in textbox instead of message box

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to put my extracted text (using regular expression) in a `TextBox`, instead of a `MessageBox`.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim source As String
    Using wc As New WebClient()
        source = wc.DownloadString("http://www.twstats.com/en71/index.php?page=rankings&mode=players")
    End Using

    Dim mcol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "page=player&amp;id=\d+"">(.+)</a>")
    For Each m As Match In mcol
        MessageBox.Show(m.Groups(1).Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Now I need to add the text displayed in the `MessageBox` in a `TextBox`.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

If I use a `TextBox` in the loop instead of the `MessageBox` it shows only the last extracted value.

Comment: Have you tried something so far in order to achieve the desired change? Do you have the wanted control in your UI? Have you looked what properties and methods the `TextBox` user control offers?

Comment: I have tried it with a richtextbox, let me just check real quick with the properties.

Comment: Then use for example `StringBuilder` to concatenate the matches into one string and after the loop add the `StringBuilder.ToString()` to the textbox.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry.. I am really noob with vb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to save your intermediate string into a variable. When adding strings one to each other, a good choice is the the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) class, that .NET offers. The operation is called [`string concatenation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) - it could be used to expand the same string with new content dynamically.

A possible solution could look like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim source As String
    Using wc As New WebClient()
        source = wc.DownloadString("http://www.twstats.com/en71/index.php?page=rankings&mode=players")
    End Using
    ' save temporarily the different strings
    Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    'alternative
    'Dim output as String = String.Empty;
    Dim mcol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "page=player&amp;id=\d+"">(.+)</a>")
    For Each m As Match In mcol
        'MessageBox.Show(m.Groups(1).Value)
        ' add every line to the "output"
        sb.AppendLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
        'output = output + Environment.NewLine + m.Groups(1).Value
    Next
    ' show the output = all lines
    textBox.Text = sb.ToString()
    'textBox.Text = output
End Sub
```

Rename the `textBox` with your variable name. It could be also a `RichTextbox` control. I have added also a second variant using just a string variable to achieve the desired result. You can choose one of the implementations.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.